# reporting with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is there a way to reporting with javascript to generate pdf file?

Comment: could you please explain more? you want to generate PDF from javascript? or want to report from javascript? or what?

Answer (score 2):

You can go for [jsPDF](http://vinaytechs.blogspot.com/2009/09/jspdf-generates-pdf-documents-using.html).

> jsPDF is an open-source library for
>   generating PDF documents using nothing
>   but Javascript. You can use it in a
>   Firefox extension, in Server Side
>   Javascript and with Data URIs in some
>   browsers.

Comment: I want to generate a PDF on the client side so I thought about JAVASCRIPT, my question is that there is a way of reporting on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "JavaScript running in a browser" then, "No, not in any practical way (since, while you can use data: URIs, they see limited browser support and limited file size)".

If you are talking server side JS, then you can generate whatever data you like, including PDF. There is [at least one library](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) that helps you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Stimulsoft Reports.JS](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/products/reports-js) that is a pure JavaScript tool. It supports export to PDF, Excel etc.